# Compare data from JTextArea in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have 4 `JTextField`s, a `JButton`, and a `JTextArea` component in a panel.

The user enters a string in the 4 text fields, and when the button is clicked, the strings in the text field are appended into the text area. The text fields are cleared for the next set of inputs to be displayed

If the user enters data that is exactly the same for 3 of the fields that was previously entered and displayed in the text area, a error message is displayed.

My question is, how can I compare the data in the text fields to the data that has already been displayed in the `JTextArea`?

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `String#contains`?  Keep a `List` of values that have been entered and check that?

Comment: Why not create an ArrayList<String> which stores the text displayed in the text area and compare text at the required index to the text in the JTextField's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `String#contains` to compare the contents of the `JTextArea` with the `JTextField`s, for example...

```
if (!textArea.getText().contains(textField.getText()) {
    // Not included in text area
}
```

The problem with this, is it doesn't distinguish between "words", for example `an` will match `banana`.  Without knowing how you are separating your words, it's difficult to make a suggestion, you might be able to use a regular expression, but we'd need more information before knowing how that might work.

Another solution would be to add each value from the text fields to a `List` and use it to instead...

```
if (!listOfValues.contains(textField.getText())) {
    listOfValues.add(textField.getText());
    // Append to text area, do other stuff
} else {
    // Show error message
}
```